# javascript validation is not working properly

Tags: php, javascript

Only one condition are exeuted other is not. Please provide the solution.

```
function a() {
    var x=document.forms["addform"]["gender"].value;
    if (x==null || x==""){
        alert("Enter gender");
        return false;
    }

    var y=document.forms["addform"]["count"].value;
    if (y==null || y==""){
        alert("enter country");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your related html code

Comment: Adding some more code and being a bit more polite does go a long way of earning that answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason both alerts are not firing (if your elements are referenced correctly) is because you are executing `return false;` in each if. This prevents any more code from firing in the function, and so the second `if` does not have a chance to fire.

In my code, I have added a variable and then I `return false;` at the end of the function if either `if` executes. This allows both alerts to fire.

```
function a()
{
  var submitform = true, x=document.forms["addform"]["gender"].value, y=document.forms["addform"]["count"].value;
  if (x===null || x=="") {
    alert("Enter gender");
    submitform = false;
  }   

  if (y===null || y=="") {
    alert("enter country");
    submitform = false;
  }
  // Added an if here
  if (submitform === false) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Thanks
Frederick

**edit: using `===` is a better practice for checking for identical values. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use) stackoverflow question for more.**

Comment: Thank you! At sixteen, I am trying to practice explaining myself to others, as it will help me with university, and also high school, as it will help me understand topics and ideas more if I can explain them to my friends and people on this site.

Comment: @Fred Great mindset to have, to explain further is that you can have as many "return" values as you want in a function but its important to note that the function will exclude the rest of the function once it hits its first "return". Consider return a final statement of your function no matter where it is located.

Answer (score 0):

One condition works and the other doesn't, that means you probably have the element name wrong for the one that isn't working. `gender` and `count` should be the `name` of the input or select elements. So your HTML should look similar to this if you're using selects:

```
<select name="gender">  <--- name = gender
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="M">Male</option>
    <option value="F">Female</option>
</select>

<select name="count">   <--- name = count
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
</select>
```

Showing all of the errors in one alert would be nicer:

```
function a()
{
    var errors = "";

    var x=document.forms["addform"]["gender"].value;
    if (x==null || x==""){
        errors += "Enter gender" + "\n";
    }

    var y=document.forms["addform"]["count"].value;
    if (y==null || y==""){
        errors += "Enter Country" + "\n";
    }

    if(errors)
    {
        alert(errors);
        return false;
    }
}
```